# Am I using 'thus' correctly in this paragraph?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I'd like to confirm if the use of 'thus' is correct in the following passage.  If it's not, please explain why, and what an alternative would be.

> I believe the most important mission of a healthcare provider is to
>   deliver the most effective and safe medical services to patients. **Thus**
>   it would be the basic principle that all the strategies and activities
>   of a healthcare provider should be patient centered.

Comment: Apart from _thus_, I would also suggest that you change “it would be the basic principle” to “it should be the basic principle” in the second sentence. It does not really make sense to explain what something would (hypothetically) be based on what you describe as a general belief of your own—it makes much more sense to explain how that general belief leads you to conclude that things _ought to be_, ideally.

Answer (score 9):

**Thus** vs **Therefore** vs **Hence**

*Thus* and *therefore* can both work in some situations, but I believe *therefore* would be a more appropriate word for you in this particular context.

**Thus** means *in this/that way* - it relates to *HOW* - the manner in which - this or that happens or comes about. It has a practical flavour. eg. Burke knocked out Byrne, thus becoming champion (consequently)

**Therefore** means *for this reason*, or *because of this or that* - it relates to deductive reasoning, it tells *WHY* this or that is so, or happened. eg. i He was late and therefore missed the bus = he was late and for this reason missed the bus. ii Payment was received two weeks after it was due; therefore, you will be charged a late fee.

**Hence** means *from this/that* - it relates to *WHERE* - position, or point in time; it tells from where or what, or to where or what, something comes, derives, or goes. eg. He wrote to his sister, hence his pride.

Comment: +1 - nice answer. Just wanted to add that [*hence*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hence) is also defined as *for this reason; therefore* (handmade and hence expensive) as well as from this time/source.

Comment: Even better in the present context would be, I feel, _as such_, which deals less with a _reason_ than a presumed acknowledgment of some state or fact: “accepting that this is so”. Since the second sentence in the paragraph builds on the first as a general basis, rather than an actual reason as such, _as such_ fits the sentiment better to my ear.